# Python26, re.match returns only the last match

Tags: python, regex

The following is the content of my source file:

```
Number= 010010
Name= Jan Mayen
Country= NORWAY
Lat=   70.9
Long=    8.7
...
```

It seems like there is a major mistake in my expression or a misunderstanding of re.match() because I need to get all properties (and not just the last one).

```
>>> pattern = re.compile(r'^(([^\n]+)=[\ ]*([^\n]+)\n)+')
>>> print pattern.match(text).groups()
>>> ('Standard deviations=   3.0   3.0   2.5   1.7   1.0   0.9   0.8   1.1   1.1   1.6  2.2   2.5 \n', 'Standard deviations', '3.0   3.0   2.5   1.7   1.0   0.9 0.8   1.1   1.1   1.6 2.2   2.5 ')
```

Any ideas?

edit: Oh.. and there is differently formatted content following, therefore I don't want to use re.findall()

Michael

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you're repeating your capturing group:

```
pattern = re.compile(r'^(...)+')
```

This means that with every match, the previous match is overwritten. This is expected behaviour in all regex engines; only few (like .NET) allow later access to the individual captures of a repeated group.

So you do in fact need to use `re.findall()` with correct parameters (e. g., a non-repeating group), avoiding matches you don't want. Since you haven't explained what sets that "following content" apart from the stuff you actually want, I can't elaborate much further here.

Comment: Okay, sounds reasonable. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You probably want `.findall()`

```
pattern = re.compile(r'^(([^\n]+)=[\ ]*([^\n]+)\n)', re.MULTILINE)
pattern.findall(data)
```

Tim's answer gives more background.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> text = '''Number= 010010
Name= Jan Mayen
Country= NORWAY
Lat=   70.9
Long=    8.7'''
>>> d = dict([re.split('=\w*', line, 1) for line in text.split('\n') if line])
>>> d
{'Country': 'NORWAY',
 'Lat': '70.9',
 'Long': '8.7',
 'Name': 'Jan Mayen',
 'Number': '010010'}
>>> d['Long']
'8.7'
```